# TWA has assetLinks but is still opening with address bar

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

Our TWA is signed with a SHA256 fingerprint and published to app store. The same key is used in digital asset link, and the validation TEST succeeds. However, the app still opens up with the address bar.

I verified that we are running a release signed build (and the same is published in app store) using the following command, and it does mention APK is in the release mode.

command: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs your_apk.apk

(command reference: https://medium.com/@chintanrathod/verify-if-apk-is-signed-with-certificate-or-debug-build-44a729e684ca)

Base code: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa

Also, here is the relevant content of the app/build.gradle file.

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
        }
    }
```

And here is the twaManifest info:

```
def twaManifest = [
    applicationId: 'in.xyz.app',
    hostName: 'xyz.in', // The domain being opened in the TWA.
    launchUrl: '/', // The start path for the TWA. Must be relative to the domain.
    name: 'XYZ', // The name shown on the Android Launcher.
    themeColor: '#FFCD59', // The color used for the status bar.
    backgroundColor: '#ffcc99' // The color used for the splash screen background.
]
```

We expect that since the 'Digital Asset Links' is valid, and the PWA + TWA is configured correctly, the app must open up without an address bar, but it doesn't.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

It seems https://xyz.in redirects to https://www.xyz.in. The first is listed to be verified in the app, the second is not. Try changing the `hostName` to www.xyz.in.

Comment: Yes, changing the hostname to www.xyz.in removes the address bar. The site is configured to redirect to www in domain configuration. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to share the APK with me, so I can take a closer look on what is wrong?